# Extract all placeHolders in a string using Node / Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, I want to retrieve all placeholder in a string, using Javascript / node :

```
SELECT * FROM myOrders WHERE order_id = {orderId} and order_date = {orderDate}
```

as array : ['orderId','orderDate'].

Is there any library I can use?

Comment: OP, I've seen your update. Look at my updated answer. And you really should use a more recent node (right now I'd recommend 5.5) and only strict mode

Comment: The `map` is important as it removes the braces at the start/end of each match

Comment: Ah -  noted.  Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var placeholders = sql.match(/\{\w+\}/g).map(s=>s.slice(1,-1));
```

Demonstration:

```js
var sql = "SELECT * FROM myOrders WHERE order_id = {orderId} and order_date = {orderDate}";
var placeholders = sql.match(/\{\w+\}/g).map(s=>s.slice(1,-1));
document.write(JSON.stringify(placeholders))
```

Note: if you're using an old version of Node (i.e. without [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), use

```
var placeholders = sql.match(/\{\w+\}/g).map(function(s){ return s.slice(1,-1) });
```